# How to automatically replace a word with another in Google Sheets using JavaScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Could someone please write a code that automatically replaces a word with another whenever it is entered or chosen in Google Sheets.

There's a drop drown list for a column in the spreadsheet that I'd like to use the code for. So whenever a specific name is chosen from that drop down list, it automatically changes to something else.

Is this even possible? Please help

Comment: Hello @Jimmy read here [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Questions. This isn't a Site who "writes" code for you.

Comment: There's always a solution. A primitive one is to copy and paste the text to notepad++ and then do the editing

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without going into script editor.

Just do in the cell you want to automatically change

```
= CELL WITH LIST
```

So an example would be if you want a cell to change then simply just do something like

```
=F6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your code:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sh=e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var col=e.range.getColumn();
  var row=e.range.getRow();
  if(sh.getName()=='Sheet57' && col==1)
  {
    sh.getRange(row,col).setValue('horse');
  }
}
```